# get user profile photo from gmail api object

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-authentication

I build this google API client object,

> serivce=build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

i succed in founding the gmail address by doing this

> serivce.users().getProfile(userId='me').execute()['emailAddress']

but I didn't found a way to get the Gmail user profile photo .

1. first- I tried to get it from getProfile but it only have history and other attributes.
2. then I tried some versions like getPhotos()/photos/getUrlPhoto but the service object doesn't have those attributes.

I would like to know how can I get from this object the user profile photo.

Answer (score 0):

The [Profile for a Gmail user](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users/getProfile#response-body) contains the following information:

> {
> "emailAddress": string,
> "messagesTotal": integer,
> "threadsTotal": integer,
> "historyId": string
> }

Unfortunately, the profile photo is not one of them.

### To retrieve a profile picture, you need to use the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people)

- Use the method [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)
- Specify a `resourceName` (e.g. `people/me`) and set `personFields` to `photos`
- This will return you the url(s) of the user's profile picture(s).
- The response will look as follows:

```
{
  "resourceName": "AAA",
  "etag": "BBB",
  "photos": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "DOMAIN_PROFILE",
          "id": "AAA"
        }
      },
      "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/CCC=s100"
    }
  ]
}
```